# Input Validation loop / read file txt with Python

Tags: python, loops, readfile

My first issue is my file is not being read by the script and truthfully I do not know why.

Second, the issue is my loop "y" or "Y" is not looping the question of account input for a user, it just continues to repeat until I hit "n" or "N" to exit....which works. (so I guess my loop works properly in that sense)

My current situation
I have a txt file that I need to read account numbers from.
I need it to loop and continue to ask for validation of account numbers even if the account number is wrong.

I would like the output to look like this

------------My needed output----------------

```
>>>
Enter the account number to be validated: 456321
Account number 456321 is not valid.
Enter another card number? Enter Y or N: Y
Enter the account number to be validated: 5552012
Account number 5552012 is valid.
Enter another card number? Enter Y or N: N
>>>
```

-----------End Needed output--------------

-----------My output at the moment---------

```
>>> 
============ RESTART: G:\Software Design\accounts.py ============
Enter the account number to be validated: 4453221
Account number 4453221 is not valid
Enter another card number? Enter Y or N: y
Enter another card number? Enter Y or N: n
>>>
```

----------End current output-----------

--------My Code----------

```
def main():

    #setting loop control
    another = 'y'

    try:
        # open file READ ONLY charge_accounts.txt
        infile = open('charge_accounts.txt', 'r')

        # Setting accountNum variable
        accountNum = int(input('Enter the account number to be validated: '))

        if accountNum in infile:
            accountNum = int(infile.readline(accountNum))
            print('Account number ' + str(accountNum) + ' is valid')
        else:
            print('Account number ' + str(accountNum) + ' is not valid')
            # Loop controls for other account inputs
            while another == 'y' or another == 'Y':
                # Get another account
                another = input('Enter another card number? ' + 'Enter Y or N: ')
                if another == 'n' or another == 'N':
                    break

        infile.close()

    # Extra credit +5 points ( catching errors )
    except IOError:
        print('An error occured trying to read')
        print('the file', charge_accounts.txt)
main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to your loop, everything you want to be repeated needs to be inside of it. So think about what you've written, `while another == y:` the *body of the loop* will be repeated. So, my advice would be to think about *where you start looping*.

Also, `accountNum in infile:` will always be false since you converted `accountNumb` to an `int`, and it needs to stay a string. Here is another head's up:

```
if accountNum in infile:
    accountNum = int(infile.readline(accountNum))
    print('Account number ' + str(accountNum) + ' is valid')
```

Will not work like you think it will anyway. When you check if something is in a `file` object, it moves the stream position to the end. This means when you `readline` it will return an empty string! If you think about it, you don't really need the `readline` anyway.

Comment: This does not make sense to me.....can you dumb it down a little? 

I know you are throwing hints out there to point me in the right direction but when I moved my While statement my script went into an endless look and just kept posting not valid nonstop....

Comment: i just spent an hour trying everything you stated above but I am not getting it

Comment: @SlowPoke did you try starting your loop right before `accountNum = int(input('Enter the account number to be validated: '))`